# SFTP upload in FileZilla results in 0000 file permissions

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, sftp, umask

Linux version 2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64
CentOS release 6.6

I am connecting to the server via SFTP (FileZilla client) with an SSH key as the user that owns the web directory (let's call it `fred`). When I upload files, they have `fred` as the file's owner and group, but the file permissions are 0000 (displayed as `----`). Obviously I don't want to have to change the permissions for every file I upload. I realize this is a umask issue, and I have tried suggestions on other websites. I've added `umask 022` to the `.bashrc` file. I've logged in as the root user and edited the `sshd_config` file so that one of the lines is as follows:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /bin/sh -c 'umask 022; /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server'
```

But none of these things have solved the problem. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

EDIT: I used NetBeans to upload a file using the same connection and the file has the correct permissions on the server, so there must be something misconfigured in FileZilla.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue for me, it looks like it's a FileZilla issue.
[see this post](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=34953)

1. SFTP uses port 22.
2. FileZilla hides the port if it is the default one, just like your browser.
3. The permission issue is a known problem and will be fixed in the next version.

All permissions were set to "0000".
The version **3.10.0.2 (2015-01-16)** on mac fixed it for me.